# Is it possible to replace the .config folder in a live iso?

Tags: lubuntu, live-environment

I used Cubic to edit an Lubuntu iso to fit my needs and so far it has worked really well. However now i need to change the default config of some packages. I know that the file that i need to replace is located in the .config directory. But i don't know where this folder is located. Since there is no user account while using cubic only the root account.
Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to answer my own question. looks like the folder I was looking for is `/etc/skel`. and as for what this directory does:

> The /etc/skel directory contains files and directories that are automatically copied over to a new user's home directory when such user is created by the useradd program.

more information can be found [here](http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html)